# Nginx reverse proxy with multiple ssl domain

Tags: centos, nginx, ssl, reverse-proxy, domain

I have problem with Nginx when I need configure it as reverse proxy for multiple locations based on source server, but on one port.

For example I have these servers:

```
server1.domain.com

server2.domain.com

server3.domain.com
```

`nginx.domain.com` is Nginx reverse proxy server

And I need access by this scheme:

```
nginx.domain.com/site -> server1.domain.com/site

(https) nginx.domain.com/site2 -> (https) server2.domain.com/site2

(https) nginx.domain.com/site3 -> (https) server3.domain.com/site3
```

But now I can access only to site2 which is first in configuration. When I change order then is working site3. Configuration of location in all servers is ok.

My `default.conf` I have following configuration.

**server1**

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name  server1.domain.com;
access_log  off;
error_log off;
# some locations
}
```

**server2**

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name  server2.domain.com;
access_log  off;
error_log off;
# some locations
}

server {
listen 443 ssl;
server_name  server2.domain.com;

include ssl/ssl.conf;
ssl     on;
ssl_certificate      ssl/server2.domain.com.crt;
ssl_certificate_key  ssl/server2.domain.com.key;    
# some locations
}
```

**server3**

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name  server3.domain.com;
access_log  off;
error_log off;
# some locations
}

server {
listen 443 ssl;
server_name  server3.domain.com;

ssl     on;
include ssl/ssl.conf;
ssl_certificate      ssl/server3.domain.com.crt;
ssl_certificate_key  ssl/server3.domain.com.key;
# some locations
}
```

In `ssl.conf` I have

```
ssl_protocols        SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers RC4:HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_timeout  10m;
```

Thanks

Comment: How does your client access them ? With SSLv3 or TLS ? Does it support SNI extension within TLS ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set up 3 servers respectively listening for requests addressed to `server[123].domain.com`.

When a request for an unknown domain kicks in, nginx serves it with the default domain. By default, nginx uses the first defined one, unless you explicitely specify another one with the `default_server` flag on the [`listen`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen) directive of one of your servers. That is why your `nginx.domain.com` requests will always be served by the default (first) server.

Now, what you wish is a reverse proxy. It is not what you asked nginx to do. You simply defined your backend servers to which you need to add another nginx server as frontend reverse-proxy.

To do so, you will need to use the [ngx_http_proxy_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html) along with the [ngx_http_upstream_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html).

Specifically, you proxy requests from a [`location`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) with [`proxy_pass`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) to your backend servers.

Here is a simple reverse-proxy server configuration that might work for you:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl; # Ensure your certificate is for nginx.domain.com;
    server_name nginx.domain.com;

    location /site1 {
        proxy_pass $scheme://server1.domain.com;
    }

    location /site2 {
        proxy_pass $scheme://server2.domain.com;
    }

    location /site3 {
        proxy_pass $scheme://server3.domain.com;
    }
}
```

Note the use of the [`$scheme`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_scheme) variable, reproducing the scheme used to connect to the frontend with connection to the backend.

I am unsure about SSL configuration on the backend. I guess you need to use the same `server_name` on each of them and the same SSL certificate as on the frontend. I do not know if you can use different certificates on backends, each with a different `server_name` and change SSL parameters for connections `proxy -> backends` with the proxy module.